How to implement global error handling for useAsyncData?
So I am using a custom ofetch instance that is defined inside a Nuxt Plugin. It has its own error handling (simplified for this example):
import type {FetchOptions} from "ofetch";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    const api = $fetch.create({
        async onResponseError({ response }) {
            // [...]
            showError({
                statusCode,
                fatal: true,
            });
        },
    });

    const get = async <T>(url: string, options?: FetchOptions) => {
        return await api<T>(url, { ...options, method: 'GET' });
    };

    return {
        provide: {
            apiGet: get,
        },
    };
});

I can now use it in my app. However, when using it inside useAsyncData, the error handling does not work if the error occurs when rendered on the server side.
This is because showError only calls the app:error hook only if executed on client side .
If I replace showError with createError, the created error is returned by useAsyncData and I can handle it there - but this is defeating my global error handling approach.
I don't want to be handling the error in every component. How can I implement this without duplicating my code? So far, this is the workaround I am working with:
export function handleErrors(...errors: (NuxtError | undefined | null)[]) {
    errors.forEach((error) => {
        if (error) {
            throw createError(error);
        }
    });
}

And its usage:
const { error } = await useAsyncData(() => $apiGet('/wrong/url'));
handleErrors(error.value);

which feels wonky.
